# Python и BeautifulSoup как вытащить текст из div с переносом строк

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
<div class="text">
  Что такое осень? Это небо.
  <br />
  Плачущее небо под ногами.
  <br />
  В лужах разлетаются птицы с облаками
  <br />
  Осень я давно с тобою не был.
  <br />
</div>
```

Я обработал его так:

txt = soup.find("div", class_="text").text

На выходе получаю текст в одну строку со склейками на месте br.

> Что такое осень? Это не**бо.Пл**ачущее небо под нога**ми.В л**ужах разлетаются птицы с облака**миОс**ень я давно с тобою не был.

Как достать текст с нормальным переносом строк?

> Что такое осень? Это небо.
> Плачущее небо под ногами.
> В лужах разлетаются птицы с облаками
> Осень я давно с тобою не был.

Comment: print('\n'.join(soup.find(class_="text").stripped_strings))

Comment: Спасибо. Всё получилось. Красивый код!